# Twitter module and weather module delays extremely joomla site

Tags: php, twitter, joomla, rss, feed

I have a joomla site and it works fine with all the modules.
I installed my site in another server but it delays too much due to Twitter module and weather module wich of course read rss feeds. If i disable these modules the site's performance is fine. Can oneone tell me what can be wrong in the new server. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without code of modules is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically on Joomla! modules for Twitter/Facebook/Weather do very little on the server - the bulk of them use Javascript to retrieve the data from the source website (i.e. not your website).

Given that, any slow-down is usually related to:

1. the speed of your internet connection *or*
2. the speed of the service providing the data

Use your browsers profiling tools ([Chrome](https://developers.google.com/speed/tools), [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/OptimizingYourWebsite/OptimizingYourWebsite.html), [Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/)) to determine exactly what's going on - you'll probably find it isn't your server.